# How to make javascript popup code shortly?

Tags: javascript, html, popup

I'd like to make javascript code for popup function shortly if possible.
May I get an idea to make below code more shortly?
Please help.

```
            function popup01() {                
                window.open('./images/MAIN/province.png');                
            }

            function popup02() {
                window.open('./images/APR/t-2019-04-Fire-Main.png');
            }

            function popup03() {
                window.open('./images/APR/t-2019-04-Fire-Main.png');
            }

            function popup04() {
                window.open('./images/APR/t-2019-04-Fire-Main.png');
            }

            function popup05() {
                window.open('./images/APR/t-2019-04-Fire-Main.png');
            }
```

Comment: The [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) comunity is a better place to ask questions about how to improve working code.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without more context but something this would be more reusable:

```
function openWindowWithImage(imageUrl) {                
  window.open(imageUrl);                
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is when you need a function parameter. You never need to create 5 separate functions to do the same thing. This is refactored code:

```
function openImagePopup(imagePath) {                
  window.open(imagePath);                
}
```

Good luck!